# How can I get last successfully deployed build id of specific artifact in YML based deploy pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to get last successfully deployed build id of specific artifact, but I didn't get any solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get last successfully deployed build id of specific artifact in YML based deploy pipeline

You could use the REST API [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1):

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=6.1-preview.8
```

My test Inline powershell task scripts:

```
$url = "GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=6.1-preview.8
"
$ReleasePipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$BuildId= $ReleasePipeline.artifacts.definitionReference.version.id

Write-Host This is Build Id: $BuildId
```

**Note:** Go to the `Agent Phase` and  select `Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token`. See [Use the OAuth token to access the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api)